# remove duplicates from comma separated string (Amazon Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon Redshift.

I have a column in that string is stored as comma separated like `Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, United Healthcare`. I want to remove the duplicates from it using `query`, so the result should be `Private, United Healthcare`. I found some solutions obviously from Stackoverflow and came to know it is possible using regular expressions.

Hence, I have tried using:

```
SELECT  regexp_replace('Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, United Healthcare', '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1') AS insurances;
```

And

```
SELECT  regexp_replace('Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, United Healthcare', '([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\g') AS insurances;
```

And also some other regular expressions but seems not working. Any solution?

Comment: Is it Postgres or Redshift? The Postgris version Redshift is based on is so old, that it can't really be compared to an up-to-date Postgres any more.

Comment: It is Redshift, but I think it is using postgrey database.

Comment: Those are two different things. Amazon Redshift is _based_ on a very old version of Postgres. It's either Redshift **or** Postgres - but not both and the fact that the suggested solution `regexp_split_to_table` does not work for you is a sign for that.

Comment: Hmm.. OK. What should I do now in that case? By the way thanks for the response.

Comment: Unsupported functions in Amazon Redshift postgrey sql: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hmm.. then in that case what can I do now?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a **User-Defined Function (UDF)** for Amazon Redshift:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_uniquify (s text)
  RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
  -- Split string by comma-space, remove duplicates, convert back to comma-separated
  return ', '.join(set(s.split(', ')))
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Testing it with:

```
select f_uniquify('Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, United Healthcare');
```

Returns:

```
United Healthcare, Private
```

If the **order of return values** is important, then it would need some more specific code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
SELECT  array_agg(DISTINCT insurances) 
FROM (SELECT  regexp_split_to_table('Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, United Healthcare'
              , ',\s+') AS insurances) x;
```

Alternative way

```
SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(regexp_split_to_array('Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, Private, United Healthcare', ',\s+')) AS insurances;
```

Checking http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/String_functions_header.html both will fail with redshift, none of those converts `text` to `text[]`

Comment: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function regexp_split_to_table("unknown", "unknown") does not exist;

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html. The function `regexp_split_to_array` is not supported by the postgrey sql on Amazon redshift.

Comment: @Dev yes i've mentioned it in the answer, [arrays aren't supported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html), i don't think regexp woud help you. Try with [create function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html) as kadalamittai supposed

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Option is to try Python UDF. Simple Python function dedupes the string and return correct version.