# How to make my Amazon Redshift UDF receive a string instead of a list?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, udf

I created this function in order to receive a `listagg()` as a parameter and remove the duplicates.

```
create or replace function reports.f_listagg_distinct (l varchar(20000))
    returns varchar(20000)
immutable
as $$
aux_list = l.split(',')
nl = []
for i in aux_list:
    if i not in nl:
        nl.append(i)
return nl
$$ language plpythonu;
```

When I run the code below I receive this Error: `TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, list found`

```
select reports.f_listagg_distinct('teste,teste,teste');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to return a distinct list of comma-separated objects, use this function from [remove duplicates from comma separated string (Amazon Redshift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39909615/remove-duplicates-from-comma-separated-string-amazon-redshift):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_uniquify (s text)
  RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
  -- Split string by comma, remove duplicates, convert back to comma-separated
  return ', '.join(set(s.split(',')))
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Testing it with:

```
select f_uniquify('test,teste,tester,teste,test');
```

Returns:

```
test, teste, tester
```